# Ineed different spacing before chapter and list of figure

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters, titles

I am writing my thesis and the specifications are as follows:

- spacing before chapter = 75mm
- spacing before list of figures etc =25mm
- Chapter needs to be in the middle  and not on the right.

But when I adjust spacing before chapter as 75mm, the spacing before list of figures also became 75mm. I used the following code. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{25mm}{\Huge}  
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{75mm}{25mm}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your preamble:

```
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{25mm}{25mm}
```

All unnumbered chapter (bibliography, list of tables, table of contents, &c., will have this spacing.

If you want to have this spacing only for some specific chapter, you can use this command just before the chapter, enclosing both (spacing command + chapter) in a group.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Can you also tell me how to align the "Chapter 1" and "the chapter name" in the middle of the page?

Comment: @DiniKadam: Do you want it horizontally centred , or left aligned or right aligned?

Comment: horizontally centered with 75mm spacing before it. I got the 75mm through the code you provided. I just need it to be in center. (Only the chapter number and chapter name have to be in the centre, not listoffigure,tableofcontents and all)

Comment: Chapter number and chapter title on the same line?

Comment: No, Chapter number and Chapter title on  different lines. Spacing between Chapter number and Chapter name 25mm.

Comment: I see. `titlesec` has tools  for section headings to be centred, or  flushleft or flushright. Use this code: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{25mm}{\Huge}`